# On page 'www.foo.com', can a script loaded from 'www.example.com' send ajax requests to 'www.example.com'?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

Is this something restricted by cross-origin policy or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You could only sent requests to `www.foo.com`.

Answer (score 4):

No. The *page* is the origin, not the script.

The page is on `www.foo.com`. The script is loaded from `www.example.com`. XHR requests can be made to `www.foo.com` but not `www.example.com`.

Comment: Your `foo.com` and `example.com` are in the opposite order to the question a little confusing ;P

Comment: @Marrowmaw: yep, that confused me as well :-)